# Многопоточность и многопроцессорность PHP

Tags: php

Возможно кто-то может поделиться кейсами использования многопоточности (какой бы она не была в PHP) или многопроцессорности PHP на продакшене. Что сподвигло применить именно PHP, что и для чего используете?

Comment: аж самому стало интересно:)

Comment: PHP как и NodeJS является однопоточным, не знаю насколько целесообразно пытаться делать его многопоточным, но вот создать несколько инстансов и объединить их с помощью того же Nginx вполне можно, данный подход позволит распределить нагрузку и значительно повысить пропускную способность проекта. Опять же, какие у вас задачи стоят для того, чтобы получить многопоточность? Что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: как оказалось, в пхп есть поддержка posix thread.

Comment: @MoloF https://www.php.net/pthreads и у меня в принципе не стоит задач работы с потоками или с процессами, просто было интересно узнать о кейсах использования, если такие есть, данных возможностей php на продакшене или в каких-то проектах.

Comment: https://amphp.org/